# Can't upload image file to webserver with IIS using PHP

Tags: php, windows, iis

I have write a small code in PHP to upload image file in our webserver running on windows advance server 2016 with IIS. I mean I just copy paste the sample code to upload files. The code runs without error but it can not save the selected file.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <Title>Covid-19 Heatmap Image Upload</Title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H5>Covid-19 Heatmap Image Upload</H5>

        <?php
            if (isset($_FILES['userfile'])){

                //pre_r($_FILES);

                $phpFileUploadErrors = array(
                0 => 'There is no error, the file uploaded with success.',
                1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.',
                2 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.',
                3 => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.',
                4 => 'No file was uploaded.',
                6 => 'Missing a temporary folder.',
                7 => 'Failed to write file to disk.',
                8 => 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload.',
                );
                
                $ext_error = false;
                // uploadable extension allowed
                $extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
                $file_ext = explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
                $file_ext = end($file_ext);

                if (!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)){
                    $ext_error = true;
                }

                // if the error of the upload is not 0 then there is error
                if ($_FILES['userfile']['error']){ 
                    echo $phpFileUploadErrors[$_FILES['userfile']['ERROR']];
                }
                elseif ($ext_error){
                    echo "Invalid file extension!";
                }
                else {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], './heatmap/'.
                    $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
                    echo "Success! Image has been uploaded.";
                }               
            }
            function pre_r($array){
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($array);
                echo '</pre>';
            }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="userfile" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any unseen error or maybe none. My path is c:/inetpub/winroot/heatmap.

Comment: Do you mean your PHP script is in c:/inetpub/winroot/ ? (or is it placed in c:/inetpub/winroot/heatmap ?)

Comment: i place the code in the heatmap folder.

Comment: In that case, please change   './heatmap/'. $_FILES['userfile']['name']) to   './'. $_FILES['userfile']['name']) in your codes and try again.  (make sure your heatmap folder is write permitted. ) .

Comment: Alternatively, you may change './heatmap/'. $_FILES['userfile']['name']) to './upload/'. $_FILES['userfile']['name']) , but you need to create a sub-folder "upload" and make it writable

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. you just need to change one thing which is your file upload location.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], './heatmap/'.

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], './'.
```

Comment: it runs perfectly in local server.

Comment: I added a IUSR tot he directory and have a rights to write and I can now upload file to  the said directory. And this new problem come out, it wont move .png file format to the directory. It only move jpg file format.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can try it again.